# KeystoneJS custom field type

Tags: reactjs, keystonejs

I am currently wondering how to create a custom field type in `KeystoneJS v4.0.0`. It looks like the documentation is out of date and I couldn't figure how to do it.

I managed to create my files `fooType.js` and `fooField.js`.

I also added:

```
Object.defineProperty(
    keystone.Field.Types,
    'Foo',
    { 
        get: function() {
            return require('./fooType.js');
        } 
    }
);
```

in `keystone.js` but it's still not working.

Comment: what error it throws ?

Comment: It basically says my type doesn't exist.
"Error: Invalid value for schema path `foo.type` in `Project`.
Did you misspell the field type?"

Comment: I honestly don't get why Keystone makes this whole process so difficult. It's really frustrating.